# Where does "this.get('filter')" comes from?

Tags: ember.js

I've been following tutorials from [Embers website](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/) and at certain point they do:

```
let filterInputValue = this.get('value');
let filterAction = this.get('filter');
filterAction(filterInputValue).then((filterResults) => this.set('results', filterResults));
```

And as far as I know **this.get('filter')** is the same thing as doing **this.filter** or **this['filter']**, right? I've been looking to their documentation about **Component** and its base object, since attributes/functions can be inherited, to find out about this **filter** but was unable to find it.

So, where does **filter** comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the action specified in the template. It's there in `rentals.hbs` in the very first code block of the page you linked:

```hbs
{{#list-filter
   filter=(action 'filterByCity')
```

edit: to answer your question about this.prop vs get(this, prop) or this.get(prop), this.prop is not the same.  however, soon it may well be.  check out [this RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0281-es5-getters.md) for more info